# Error while trying to mount pendrive with exFAT

Tags: usb, mount, filesystem, usb-drive, exfat

When I insert my pendrive I am given this error:

> Error mounting: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'

This is the VX-EDU version.

Answer (score 3):

To mount exFAT, you need the `exfat-fuse` package:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

You can then use the normal mount command, e.g.:

```
mount -t /dev/sdd /mnt
```

Comment: Does this also make exFAT volumes mount automatically, in the circumstances where they would do so if they were FAT16/FAT32 volumes? (Most desktop Ubuntu systems are set up to automatically mount USB mass storage devices when they are connected.)